# CGAL 3D Convex Hull with own 'Traits' implementation contains internal points

Tags: 3d, traits, cgal, convex-hull

My aim is to compute with CGAL the static Convex Hull of a set of 3D points. I read the article at [the proper CGAL documentation page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/index.html) and implemented a first algorithm in which I get a `Polyhedron_3` (the convex hull) from the set of 3D points I had previously converted into `Kernel::Point_3` structure. It works.

Then I tried to apply the algorithm directly to the original points, *i.e.*, without applying the conversion to `Kernel::Point_3` structure. From the above mentioned documentation I understood that the way for doing this is implementing a new class of Traits, which defines the geometric primitives used by the algorithm. So I followed the [*ConvexHullTraits_3* Concept Reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/classConvexHullTraits__3.html), and by taking a look to the *Convex_hull_traits_3.h* CGAL file, I produced the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Convex_hull_traits_3.h>
#include <CGAL/internal/Projection_traits_3.h>
#include <CGAL/predicates/kernel_ftC3.h>
#include <CGAL/Kernel/global_functions_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel My_kernel;

class My_point_3
{
private:

    typedef My_kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
    Point_3 point; //!< coordinates of the point
    int index; //!< additional info about the point

public:

    //constructors
    My_point_3() : index(-1), point() {};
    My_point_3(const double x, const double y, const double z, int i = -1) : index(i), point(x, y, z) {};
    My_point_3(Point_3& point, int i = -1) : index(i), point(point) {};
    My_point_3(Point_3 point, int i = -1) : index(i), point(point) {};

    //access to members for reading
    const int & Index() const { return index; }
    const Point_3 & Point()const { return point; }

    //access to members for writing
    int & Index() { return index; }
    Point_3 & Point() { return point; }

    //operators
    bool operator==(const My_point_3 &p) const
    {
        return (point == p.Point());
    }
    bool operator!=(const My_point_3 &p) const
    {
        return !(*this == p);
    }

    //see §5.3 of https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#sectionextensiblekernel
    const double & x() const { return point.x(); }
    const double & y() const { return point.y(); }
    const double & z() const { return point.z(); }
};

//projection traits implemented to satisfy https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_2/group__PkgConvexHull2Functions.html#gac13b4efbc337c7a8d5ad418521edcd4f
template <int dim>
class My_projection_traits_3
{
public:

    //Point_2
    typedef My_point_3                                Point_2;

    //Less_signed_distance_to_line_2
    typedef CGAL::internal::Less_signed_distance_to_line_projected_3<My_kernel, dim> Default_less_signed_distance_to_line_2;
    template <int d>
    class Less_signed_distance_to_line_projected_3
    {
    public:
        typedef My_point_3           Point_3;
        typedef My_kernel::Point_2   Point_2;
        My_kernel::FT x(const My_kernel::Point_3 &p) const { return CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, d>::x(p); }
        My_kernel::FT y(const My_kernel::Point_3 &p) const { return CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, d>::y(p); }

        Point_2 project(const Point_3& p) const
        {
            return Point_2(x(p.Point()), y(p.Point()));
        }

        bool operator()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r, const Point_3& s) const
        {
            Default_less_signed_distance_to_line_2 predicate;
            return predicate(project(p), project(q), project(r), project(s));
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };
    typedef Less_signed_distance_to_line_projected_3<dim>    Less_signed_distance_to_line_2;

    Less_signed_distance_to_line_2 less_signed_distance_to_line_2_object() const
    {
        return Less_signed_distance_to_line_2();
    }

    //Orientation_2
    template <int d>
    class Orientation_projected_3
    {
    public:
        typedef My_point_3           Point_3;
        typedef My_kernel::Point_2   Point_2;
        My_kernel::FT x(const My_kernel::Point_3 &p) const { return CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, d>::x(p); }
        My_kernel::FT y(const My_kernel::Point_3 &p) const { return CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, d>::y(p); }

        Point_2 project(const Point_3& p) const
        {
            return Point_2(x(p.Point()), y(p.Point()));
        }

        CGAL::Orientation operator()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r) const
        {
            return CGAL::orientation(project(p), project(q), project(r));
        }

        typedef CGAL::Orientation result_type;
    };
    typedef Orientation_projected_3<dim>                     Orientation_2;

    Orientation_2 orientation_2_object() const
    {
        return Orientation_2();
    }

    //Left_turn_2
    struct Left_turn_2
    {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Point_2& p, const Point_2& q, const Point_2& r) const
        {
            Orientation_2 predicate;
            return (predicate(p, q, r) == CGAL::LEFT_TURN);
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    Left_turn_2 left_turn_2_object() const
    {
        return Left_turn_2();
    }

    //Less_xy_2
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Compare_x_2              Compare_x_2;
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Less_y_2                 Less_y_2;
    struct Less_xy_2
    {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Point_2& p, const Point_2& q) const
        {
            Compare_x_2 predicate1;
            CGAL::Comparison_result crx = predicate1(p.Point(), q.Point());
            if (crx == CGAL::SMALLER) { return true; }
            if (crx == CGAL::LARGER) { return false; }
            Less_y_2 predicate2;
            return predicate2(p.Point(), q.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    Less_xy_2 less_xy_2_object() const
    {
        return Less_xy_2();
    }

    //Less_yx_2
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Compare_y_2              Compare_y_2;
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Less_x_2                 Less_x_2;
    struct Less_yx_2
    {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Point_2& p, const Point_2& q) const
        {
            Compare_y_2 predicate1;
            CGAL::Comparison_result cry = predicate1(p.Point(), q.Point());
            if (cry == CGAL::SMALLER) { return true; }
            if (cry == CGAL::LARGER) { return false; }
            Less_x_2 predicate2;
            return predicate2(p.Point(), q.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    Less_yx_2 less_yx_2_object() const
    {
        return Less_yx_2();
    }

    //Equal_2
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Equal_x_2                Equal_x_2;
    typedef typename CGAL::internal::Projector<My_kernel, dim>::Equal_y_2                Equal_y_2;
    struct Equal_2
    {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Point_2& p, const Point_2& q) const
        {
            Equal_x_2 predicate1;
            Equal_y_2 predicate2;
            return predicate1(p.Point(), q.Point()) & predicate2(p.Point(), q.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    Equal_2 equal_2_object() const
    {
        return Equal_2();
    }
};

class Point_triple
{
protected:
    typedef My_kernel::FT                   FT;
    typedef My_kernel::Point_3              Point_3;
    typedef My_kernel::Vector_3             Vector_3;

    Point_3 p_, q_, r_;
public:

    Point_triple() {}

    Point_triple(const Point_3 &p, const Point_3 &q, const Point_3 &r): p_(p), q_(q), r_(r) {}

    const Point_3& p() const { return p_; }
    const Point_3& q() const { return q_; }
    const Point_3& r() const { return r_; }
};

typedef CGAL::Convex_hull_traits_3<My_kernel> Default_traits;

class My_traits
{
public:
    typedef My_point_3                    Point_3;
    typedef My_kernel::Segment_3          Segment_3;
    typedef My_kernel::Triangle_3         Triangle_3;
    typedef Point_triple                  Plane_3;

    class Construct_segment_3
    {
    public:

        Segment_3 operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q) const
        {
            Default_traits::Construct_segment_3 object;
            return object(p.Point(), q.Point());
        }

        typedef Segment_3 result_type;
    };

    class Construct_plane_3
    {
    public:

        Plane_3 operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r) const
        {
            CGAL::Convex_hull_traits_3<My_kernel>::Construct_plane_3 object;
            CGAL::Point_triple<My_kernel> plane = object(p.Point(), q.Point(), r.Point());
            return Point_triple(plane.p(), plane.q(), plane.r());
        }

        typedef Plane_3 result_type;
    };

    class Construct_triangle_3
    {
    public:

        Triangle_3 operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r) const
        {
            Default_traits::Construct_triangle_3 object;
            return object(p.Point(), q.Point(), r.Point());
        }

        typedef Triangle_3 result_type;
    };

    class Equal_3
    {
    public:

        bool operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q) const
        {
            Default_traits::Equal_3 predicate;
            return predicate(p.Point(), q.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    class Collinear_3
    {
    public:

        bool operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r) const
        {
            Default_traits::Collinear_3 predicate;
            return predicate(p.Point(), q.Point(), r.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    class Coplanar_3
    {
    public:

        bool operator ()(const Point_3& p, const Point_3& q, const Point_3& r, const Point_3& s) const
        {
            Default_traits::Coplanar_3 predicate;
            return predicate(p.Point(), q.Point(), r.Point(), s.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    class Has_on_positive_side_3
    {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Plane_3& pl, const Point_3& p) const
        {
            Default_traits::Orientation_3 predicate;
            return (predicate(pl.p(), pl.q(), pl.r(), p.Point()) == CGAL::POSITIVE);
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    class Less_distance_to_point_3
    {
    public:

        bool operator ()(const Point_3 & p, const Point_3 & q, const Point_3 & r) const
        {
            Default_traits::Less_distance_to_point_3 predicate;
            return predicate(p.Point(), q.Point(), r.Point());
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    class Less_signed_distance_to_plane_3
    {

    public:

        bool operator()(const Plane_3 & h, const Point_3 & p, const Point_3 & q) const
        {
            const My_kernel::Point_3 & hp = h.p();
            const My_kernel::Point_3 & hq = h.q();
            const My_kernel::Point_3 & hr = h.r();
            return CGAL::has_smaller_signed_dist_to_planeC3(
                hp.x(), hp.y(), hp.z(), 
                hq.x(), hq.y(), hq.z(), 
                hr.x(), hr.y(), hr.z(), 
                p.Point().x(), p.Point().y(), 
                p.Point().z(), q.Point().x(), 
                q.Point().y(), q.Point().z()
            );
        }

        typedef bool result_type;
    };

    typedef My_projection_traits_3<2> Traits_xy_3;
    typedef My_projection_traits_3<0> Traits_yz_3;
    typedef My_projection_traits_3<1> Traits_xz_3;

    Construct_segment_3 construct_segment_3_object() const
    {
        return Construct_segment_3();
    }

    Construct_plane_3 construct_plane_3_object() const
    {
        return Construct_plane_3();
    }

    Construct_triangle_3 construct_triangle_3_object() const
    {
        return Construct_triangle_3();
    }

    Collinear_3 collinear_3_object() const
    {
        return Collinear_3();
    }

    Coplanar_3 coplanar_3_object() const
    {
        return Coplanar_3();
    }

    Less_distance_to_point_3 less_distance_to_point_3_object() const
    {
        return Less_distance_to_point_3();
    }

    Has_on_positive_side_3 has_on_positive_side_3_object() const
    {
        return Has_on_positive_side_3();
    }

    Equal_3 equal_3_object() const
    {
        return Equal_3();
    }

    Less_signed_distance_to_plane_3 less_signed_distance_to_plane_3_object() const
    {
        return Less_signed_distance_to_plane_3();
    }

    Traits_xy_3 construct_traits_xy_3_object() const
    {
        return Traits_xy_3();
    }

    Traits_yz_3 construct_traits_yz_3_object() const
    {
        return Traits_yz_3();
    }

    Traits_xz_3 construct_traits_xz_3_object() const
    {
        return Traits_xz_3();
    }
};


typedef My_kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<My_point_3>               Surface_mesh;

int main()
{
    std::vector<My_point_3> input_points;
    input_points.push_back(My_point_3(Point_3(0, 0, 0), 1));
    input_points.push_back(My_point_3(Point_3(1, 0, 0), 2));
    input_points.push_back(My_point_3(Point_3(0, 1, 0), 3));
    input_points.push_back(My_point_3(Point_3(0, 0, 1), 4));
    input_points.push_back(My_point_3(Point_3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 5));

    Surface_mesh mesh;
    CGAL::convex_hull_3(input_points.begin(), input_points.end(), mesh, My_traits());

    Surface_mesh::Vertex_iterator v;
    for (v = mesh.vertices_begin(); v != mesh.vertices_end(); v++)
    {
        std::cout << input_points[*v].Index() << " (" << input_points[*v].Point() << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<s>When I try to compile, however, it gives me the following error: [...]</s> *(**Edit**: solved by updating CGAL from 4.12 to 4.13 and some other corrections --- see edit history and comments below for details)*.

The code compiles; however, when I iterate on the vertices of the convex hull in a minimal example (see *main* function above), also vertices not on the convex hull are printed.

The question is: what am I doing wrong with my code? what is missing?

Comment: Your code has a number of errors (extra `typename`, shadowing `dim`, etc) which make it harder to concentrate on the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. In fact, I'm not confident with templates, so I focused on removing some errors with your suggestions (I hope I've done it correctly), but unfortunately the problem remains. Other suggestions?

Comment: You are also using many things from namespace CGAL without CGAL::, like LEFT_TURN, Comparison_result, etc. I don't see how this can even come close to the error message you show. Less_distance_to_point_3::operator() also has a strange number of arguments, see https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classKernel_1_1LessDistanceToPoint__3.html .

Comment: Thank you! I revised all the code checking for missing `CGAL::` prefixes, added some of them and also included explicitly two other headers. Unfortunately the compilation errors remain the same. Regarding the operator `Less_distance_to_point_3::operator()`, I followed the [CGAL ConvexHullTraits_3 Concept Reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/classConvexHullTraits__3.html#a44e03ba1b3655d3f07bd45b30e1864e9), in which they say that the class must implement "a constructor taking a single Point_3 object and bool operator()(Point_3 q, Point_3 r)".

Comment: Compiler error messages indicate clearly that you are missing Less_yx_2 at least. You are also missing Orientation_2 (not your fault, it was missing in the doc until https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3366 ). construct_traits_xy_3_object is also missing.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/3421 for Less_distance_to_point_3 doc.

Comment: By the way, what version of CGAL are you using? Use_advanced_filtering does not seem to exist in the current version.

Comment: I added `Less_yx_2` and `Orientation_2`, that were missing, beyond the reason you mentioned, because I was following [_Traits_xy_3_ documentation in _ConvexHullTraits_3_ Concept Reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/classConvexHullTraits__3.html#a9a735716bb623fa4a34a7b74f5291b08), and therefore the [_ch_bykat()_
 function reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_2/group__PkgConvexHull2Functions.html#gac13b4efbc337c7a8d5ad418521edcd4f), where they not included `Less_yx_2` and `Orientation_2`.

Comment: I also added `traits_xy_3_object` (missing because in the same documentation page, paragraph _Operations_, they say that those functions should be added for _functions_ and _predicates_, but in the above list, `Traits_xy_3` were described as _classes_). The version of CGAL I'm using is 4.12. I'll try to update my version. Thank you for letting me notice that.

Comment: As shown at the very end of https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/classConvexHullTraits__3.html , it is `construct_traits_xy_3_object`, not `traits_xy_3_object`. Yes, that's weird and inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, I missed it, and now I fixed. I managed to update to CGAL-4.13 and now the code compiles. However, the results seem not correct, as I tried to explained in the edited post.

Comment: In your example, the 5 points are in convex position.

Comment: Amazed by myself. I tried with (0.25, 0.25, 0.25) instead of (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) and it seems to work. What should I do with the post now?

Comment: Best would be if you could post an answer that summarizes all the information you learned. More precisely, the answer should be such that, had you found that text before posting your question, you wouldn't have needed to post a question at all. If you don't want to, you can just leave the question as is. I think SO disapproves of removing questions unless they are spam or a typo.